# Using a mutex in an audio callback

Tags: multithreading, audio

When writing an audio application, it's generally well understood that there are certain unbounded operations should never be used in the audio driver callback.  These operations typically include things like allocating memory, reading or writing disk or network, locking a mutex/critical section etc...

I'm currently re-writing the audio engine of my music app Cantabile (http://www.cantabilesoftware.com) and the entire engine is now completely lock free, except for one area, on which I'd appreciate the opinion of others.

Cantabile can leverage multiple processors/cores to process audio.  It does this by constructing a tree of work items and then waking a pool of threads which all contribute to getting the job done.  All of the threads in the thread pool run at the highest priority possible (time critical + vista mmcss boost on Windows) and don't do anything else except audio processing (ie: they're not used for other background utility tasks).

To implement all this I use a condition variable to wake the worker threads and a single critical section to serialize access to the work item tree.  The critical section has a spin count and is only locked just long enough for the worker to pull the next work item from the tree.

My rationale for this being ok is:

1. The spin counts should always cover the time needed for any other threads to release the lock.
2. Even if the spin count isn't enough there shouldn't be issues with priority inversion because all the threads are running at time critical priority.
3. None of the worker threads perform any other potentially unbounded operations (except possibly when processing a poorly-written plugin but there's not much I can do about that).

I've run many tests against this and it seems to be working well, but matters like this have a habit of tripping one up when least expected.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: No guarantees means no guarantees. "My threads have high priority" ≠ "there cannot be a priority inversion". Use boost.lockfree and have a clean conscience :)

Comment: @DarkWanderer care to elaborate on why multiple threads at same priority all contenting for one mutex can cause priority inversion issues?  The point here is to not let one of the real-time threads be stalled waiting for a mutex being held by a lower priority thread.  In my case all the threads in question are all contributing to getting the same real-time task completed asap.

Comment: @DarkWanderer as for boost.lockfree I do use lock free data structures (though not boost) in all other interactions with the audio engine.  It's this one particular case where I haven't found way to use lock-free solution to the problem at hand - namely a pool of worker threads executing a set of work items in a dependency tree.  In the end I've gone with this approach and it's working well - particularly after tuning it to minimize locking.

Comment: Well, AFAIK there always can be situation where a thread will be rescheduled while having a lock acquired - if only for another thread with same priority to wait for it. While in practice it is unlikely to cause problems, it theoretically can. Not a priority inversion, you're right, but still not what you seek for